# Adicionar coluna numa tabela (chave estrangeira) usando entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho um projecto em c# numa faze relativamente avançada.

A minha BD já contem alguns dados para testes.

Estou a usar code first migrations do entity Framework

Tenho as tabelas Users e Imagens. A tabela imagens tem apenas as Colunas Id e CaminhoDaImagem.

Quero que a minha tabela Users passa aceder à tabela Imagens por isso criei uma chave estrangeira que é o IdDaImagem (chave primária da tabela Imagens).

O problema surge quando digito a comando Update-database, aqui está o erro:

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Imagems_ImagemId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-BrainCast-20161008051801", table "dbo.Imagems", column 'Id'.

Existe um conflito mesmo que a tabela imagens não contenha quaisquer dados.

Alguém tem ideia de como posso resolver isto. Já andei a pesquisar mas não entendo as soluções que são apresentadas, também podem indicar tutoriais.

Comment: pode colocar o seu código mais importante, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O campo da imagem na tabela de Usuários pode aceitar valores nulos?

Não sei bem ao certo como você estruturou suas classes, mas pela mensagem apresentada, ao tentar incluir a coluna, como já existem registros na tabela Usuário, ele irá definir o valor como nulo, pois ele ainda não sabe o que precisa inserir na mesma, e se a coluna na tabela Usuários não aceitar nulo ele irá gerar este erro.